# Shell script that transfer file which takes date from till(Nov1) to to(Dec1) from name

Tags: shell-script, shell, scripting, rsync, scp

Okay so this shell script is might sound complicated but I don't know how to achieve this.

so here is the requirement.

[image]

note the above files kindly.

filname are as follows.

```
Meter_20200120100846.xls
Meter_20200121100846.xls
Meter_20200122100846.xls
Meter_20200123100846.xls
Meter_20200124100846.xls
Meter_20200125100846.xls
```

So I want to create such a script that copy these files to another server. but here's the twist the number in the end is the date of that file.
so 20200120 in the file 1 means it was created on 20/01/2020.

so basically i want to created such a script that takes the input as 20/01/2020 or 20200120 **to** 25/01/2020 or 20200125  and copy all files to another server with same name.

I can use anything to copy scp, sftp or rsync in the command.

basically creating such a script that take from date to end date and copy all the files to another server.

To be honest I don't know if it's even possible to do that.

but guys if you are able to know such solution then it would really help me out.

**Thanks and Regards,**
**Sagar Mandal**

Comment: [Please don't post images of text](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4086/22222). Instead, paste the text directly into your question and use the [formatting tools](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/help/formatting) to format it as code. It would make our life much easier if we could simply copy your file names instead of having to type the names letter by letter looking at your image.

Comment: Hey man, I just added filename.and it's gonna be an automation type of script so yeah.. help me out in this.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly:

```
# Here you set the range of dates
from="20200121" 
to="20200125"
for f in *.xls; do 
  [[ $(date -d "${f:6:8}" +%s) -ge $(date -d "$from" +%s) ]] &&
  [[ $(date -d "${f:6:8}" +%s) -le $(date -d "$to" +%s) ]] &&
  echo "$f in range" || # Here your actions
  echo "$f not in range" 
done
```

Output:

```
Meter_20200120100846.xls not in range
Meter_20200121100846.xls in range
Meter_20200122100846.xls in range
Meter_20200123100846.xls in range
Meter_20200124100846.xls in range
Meter_20200125100846.xls in range
```

Comment: Bro the number after 202001120 is dynamic it can be changed

Comment: @SagarMandal Sorry, I don't understand. In my code the names of the files are not changed (copying them from your post).

Comment: so your saying that it doesn't matter if the first file is named as Meter_20200121100846.xls and second file is Meter_20200124091834.xls, so will your code work with this file too.

Comment: My code takes `Meter_<20200125>100846.xls`, as I understand the date (20200125), the rest is ignored.

Comment: Thnks man really, I'll test this and let you know for sure. so what would you suggest, what is the easiest way to send files to a remote server

Comment: @SagarMandal "what is the easiest way to send files to a remote server", in this I can't be of much help, sorry :(

Comment: It's cool man.. no issues. Btw Thnk you so much your code is awsome man. it worked like a charm. the only thing I'm left if no sending these files to a remote server. can you just me something like what to do in the # here your action part... also a quick question why the first file isn't in the range(20200120).

Comment: @SagarMandal just replace the `echo $f in range` with your preferred transfer command. We can't help you choose that, it will depend on how you can access your server. The classic options are `scp`, `rsync`, `ftp`.

Comment: @SagarMandal "also a quick question why the first file isn't in the range(20200120). ", oh because I just set it to be equal or greater than day 21, just to set an example. You can change the range all you want setting the `from` and `to` variables. In my code the comparison is `-ge` (greater or equal), and `-le` (less or equal).

Comment: Thanks @terdon buddy :-)

Comment: Thanks you so much @guillermochamorro man...really man

Answer (score 0):

date command is what you are looking for

```
$ date -d 1/25/2020 +%Y%m%d
20200125
```

`-d mm/dd/yyyy`  - give the input date to the command.

`+%Y%m%d`       -  what you want your output to be.

- `%Y`  - year in four digits
- `%m`  - month in two digits
- `%d`  - date of the month in two digits.

Comment: but how will you pick files from "this date" to "this date" and then copy them to another server.